# Print/Print Preview in WPF

Tags: wpf, printing, preview

I have wpf based application, just wondering how to get print/print preview of wpf controls.

like some window/page has panel control which has multiple controls in it like chart + graph + data grid (data grid can have hell of records so coming with scrollbar)

i wanted to have print version of it but dont want to just print visual part but also scrolled part...

please suggest solutions. thanks

Answer (score 0):

There no way to automagically print your screen adapted for paper printing.
You need to use other methods to print your grids and graphs, like these:

1. [WpfReports](http://wpfreports.codeplex.com/)

[image]

2. [Janrep's WPF multipage report](http://janrep.blog.codeplant.net/post/WPF-Multipage-Reports-Part-I.aspx)

[image]